# How to remove slash from url using htaccess

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm rewriting url using htaccess.
Here is my .htaccess file

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule (.*)/$ post.php?&url=$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) $1.php [L]
```

I want to remove slash from the end of the url. 
For example :

```
https://www.example.com/some-post/
```

to

```
https://www.example.com/some-post
```

PS. Not From index.php but  a different page.

Answer (score 1):

To force a redirect from URLs ending in `/` to the same URL without the slash just do:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ $1 [L,R=301,QSA]
```